How to make the ingredient list align at the center while keeping the current layout
Based on the photo and code below, how do I make the ingredient list align at the center along with the ingredients title? I tried using custom width for both of the SizedBox for the ingredients, but it doesn't work well for different ingredients. How do I take the maximum length for the current ingredient to set the width? or any other solutions are welcome.  
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:meals/models/meal.dart';

class MealDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MealDetailsScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.meal,
  });

  final Meal meal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(meal.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 15,
            horizontal: 15,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface, // Background color of the container
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), // Rounded corners
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: Image.network(
                    meal.imageUrl,
                    height: 300,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 14),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Ingredients',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.borel().fontFamily,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 24,
                        ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 14),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      for (final ingredient in meal.ingredients)
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                                width: 50,
                                child: Text(
                                  ingredient.contains(' ') ? ingredient.split(' ').first : '',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                                      ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 8),
                              // Ingredient name
                              SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                                child: Text(
                                  ingredient.contains(' ') ? ingredient.split(' ').skip(1).join(' ') : ingredient,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                                      ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // Steps Section
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Steps',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                            fontFamily: GoogleFonts.borel().fontFamily,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24,
                          ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          for (final entry in meal.steps.asMap().entries)
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6),
                              child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  // Step number
                                  Text(
                                    '${entry.key + 1}. ', // Display step number
                                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 6),
                                  // Step description
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      entry.value,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                                          ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  // ),
                    
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}


